# How to extract certain argruements from the system command "ps"?

Tags: sh

I am working on a server and client program. I run ./server 8080 to specify the port from the command line. In my client program I wrote system("ps -aux | grep -w server | grep -v grep");. It does show PID:197435  0.0  0.0   4360   908 pts/1    S+   19:34   0:00 ./server 8080. How would I go about formatting my grep to only show the port 8080?

Comment: This is a shell question, not a C question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the output of `ps`, you could just read the command and arguments from `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`. Here the arguments are null-delimited, so you will need to convert nulls to spaces.

Assuming I had `nc -l localhost 8080` running as pid 3279374, that
would look like this:

```
$ tr '\0' ' ' < /proc/3279374/cmdline
nc -l localhost 8080
```

You can also ask `ps` to display just the information you want:

```
$ ps -p 3279374 -o args=
nc -l localhost 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either:

```
ps ax -o args | awk '$(NF-1) ~ /(^|\/)server$/ && $NF~/^[0-9]{4}$/ {print $NF}'
```

Like `grep -w`, except match `server` in the second last argument specifically*.

```
ps ax -o args | grep -w 'serve[r]' | awk '$NF ~ /^[0-9]{4}$/ {print $NF}'
```

Using `grep -w` as you were - but this can match `server` as any argument of any running process.

- `ps ax -o args` is like `ps aux`, but prints only one column - the command and arguments.
- *The first example matches `server` in the second last field, because for example if `server` is a script, the interpreter will be the first field, and the script `server` (or `/path/to/server`) the second (even if `server` is executable, and you invoked it directly).
- eg. It may look like `/usr/bin/python3 ./server 8080` if `server` is a python script.
- If `server` has other arguments, you can change the field numbers to match.
- `grep -w 'serve[r]'` avoids matching grep itself.
- `ps ax -o args | awk '/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])server($|[[:alnum:]_])/ && $NF~/^[0-9]{4}$/ {print $NF}'` is equivalent to the second example, using awk only.
- Not every unix like OS implements procfs (eg Mac, OpenBSD). But `ps` is POSIX (and the only question tag is `sh`).